# How to create an interface that allows for loading an object?

Tags: php, interface, static

I have created an interface meant to be implemented by users. The only real requirements I have is that the user's implement a Save() and a Load() method.  Now save is simple, but the problem I'm having is with Load().

In order for Load() to be part of the interface it would need to be an instance method. But the nature of it is to return a new object that has been loaded from a database. This would imply that Load() needs to be defined as static.  Static methods aren't enforced by the interface.

**How can I require users who implement the interface to write their own code for Load()?**

I'm using PHP5.4 which does require that constructor definitions are followed in subclasses, so one thought was to change this into an Abstract Class and define a constructor that takes an $id variable. If it's `null` we create a new object, if it's set then load the object. I'd much prefer to keep this setup as an interface. There also is some concern of ambiguity and some user implementing their constructor incorrectly. It's easier to document and describe what `load()` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does "a method that returns an object" immediately mean that it has to be static? Static isn't a blanket "go-to" on object creation - it actually serves a specific purpose.

Anyway. There is nothing stopping you from defining an interface that requires the implementation of a static method, as follows, if your heart so desires :

```
interface MyTestInterface {
   public static function Load();
}
class MyTest implements MyTestInterface {
   public static function Load() { 
       echo "Test";
   }
}
```

Fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xcoQZh

There is nothing stopping you from defining a method requiring implementation, either through an interface or an abstract class, when the method is static. However, consider the actual `static` use in this case....

Comment: Static is used because it wouldn't make sense to create an instance of the object in order to load another instance of the object. And I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that an interface cannot **require** a static method be implemented.  You can override it, and with late static bindings it should work, but if they didn't override it there'd be no compile errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, statics can be enforced in interfaces. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#96137

Comment: The problem is that I need to call the specific `Load()` method, but without an instance already I'd have to know the class name. In this example I'd need to know `MyTest` to be able to call `MyTest::Load()`. But I think I have an extension to this that may work.

Comment: @chris: Have you considered Inversion of Control or Dependency Injection? These would allow you to either query a lookup table or to pass in a class instance. Also, **your question** suggested the static method. All I did was to say "no, not a good idea, but if you want to do it, here's how".

Comment: I edited the question, I meant that Load() would need to be defined static. We are using Zend Framework 2 and the Service Manager it provides. We are using it to give us a single manager class, that will then implement the strategy pattern. Figure out which class is appropriate for the object we're trying to load and call that classes load.  I edited your answer to include this, but it looks like the edit hasn't been added. I'm going to be implementing and testing this today and tomorrow, I'll post back with what we get.